# What is the value of a class variable which is initialised in the same class again?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

This code replaces vowels with * in swear words given as input. Now when I use "+" operator, a class instance is created and initialised again with input as both strings ("t*mn" and "d*ck").

My doubt is that what happens to @value variable in this case? Can the call to new instance in "+" method replace the value of @value in original class?

```
class Bowlderize

  def initialize(string)
    @value = string.gsub(/[aeiou]/, "*")
  end

  def +(other)
    Bowlderize.new(self.to_s + other.to_s)
  end

  def to_s
    @value
  end
end

mybow = Bowlderize.new("tamn ") + "duck"
puts mybow.to_s
```

1st Edit:

This code returns "d*ck". If the new call to the same class cannot change the @value, then how is d*ck returned?

```
class Bowlderize

  def initialize(string)
    @value = string.gsub(/[aeiou]/, "*")
  end

  def +(other)
    Bowlderize.new(other.to_s)
  end

  def to_s
    @value
  end
end

mybow = Bowlderize.new("tamn ") + "duck"
puts mybow.to_s
```

Comment: Are you sure using swear words is essential to the understanding of your programming issue? Please [edit] them out or replace them with appropriate terms.

Comment: You may want to fix the spelling of "bowdlerize".  Also, and more importantly, note that `"duck"` is not an object of your class, but just a string, so calling `to_s` on it doesn't really do anything.  Maybe you meant `Bowlderize.new("duck")`.

Answer (score 1):

@value in the original instance is not changed.  You've just created a new instance with the combined @value.

In fact there isn't really any way to change @value in an existing object, because none of the class methods modify that instance variable.

Comment: There are ways to cheat, e.g. `instance_eval`.

Comment: @undur_gongor better still `instance_variable_set`